# Inner Structure Initialization Don't Work - C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying a code that just doesn't work. What happens is when the output is written, the color string comes empty even if it's initialized.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

struct Shape {
  virtual string str() const = 0;
};

struct Circle : Shape {
  Circle() = default;

  string str() const override {
    ostringstream oss;
    oss << "Circle";
    return oss.str();
  }
};

struct ColoredShape : Shape {
  Shape& shape;
  string color;

  ColoredShape(Shape& shape, /*const string&*/string color) : shape(shape), color(color) {}

  string str() const override {
    ostringstream oss;
    oss << shape.str() << " has the color " << color << endl;
    return oss.str();
  }
};

int main()
{
  Circle circle;

  ColoredShape v1{ circle, "v1" };
  ColoredShape v2{ v1, "v2" };
  ColoredShape v3{ v2, "v3" };
  cout << v3.str() << endl;

  /* Output is
  Circle has the color v1
    has the color v2
    has the color v3
  */

  ColoredShape n3{ ColoredShape{ ColoredShape{ circle, "v1" }, "v2" }, "v3" };
  cout << n3.str() << endl;

  /* Output is (no colors)
  Circle has the color
    has the color
    has the color v3
  */

  return 0;
}
```

I couldn't figure out why this happens. In the code above, the initialization is exactly the same except the second one is initialized inside another structure. Can you help?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ColoredShape{ ColoredShape{ circle, "v1" }, "v2" }` is wrong as you take (non const) reference to a temporary.

So you have dangling reference.

I suggest to remove the extension allowing to bind temporary to non const reference.

Comment: Isn't it stored in the stack so shouldn't it be a real reference as long as the main function is live?

Comment: @MeCe It is destroyed at the end of the statement. Hence, why it becomes a dangling reference immediately after the statement is executed.